# Full text search does not find some specific words, which not included in stop words

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I am implementing the full text search on table called programming_language.
It contains multiple rows with 'name' column such as java, javascript, etc.

Initially I didn't have full text index so I did the following:

```
ALTER TABLE `Example`.`programming_language` 
ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `fi_name` (`name`) WITH PARSER ngram VISIBLE;
-- This returns nothing
```

After this, full text search seems to work for most of the rows. However, some words such as 'java' aren't found by query.
My sql look like following

```
select * from programming_language
where match(name)
against("java" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
-- This returns nothing
```

or

```
select * from programming_language
where match(name)
against("java" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
-- This returns nothing
```

(also tried java* but didn't work as well)

I am expecting to get back java and javascript, but none of them get returned.
Is there anything wrong with my sql?

I am fairly new to this topic and would appreciate for any helps.

Answer (score 0):

it is your parser  ngram

Without it no problem

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE programming_language (
  `word_id` INTEGER,
  `name` VARCHAR(15)
);

ALTER TABLE `programming_language` 
ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `fi_name` (`name`) ;
-- This returns nothing


INSERT INTO programming_language
  (`word_id`, `name`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'SWIFT'),
  ('2', 'JAVA'),
  ('3', 'java'),
  ('4', 'SENTENCE'),
  ('5', 'PETITION'),
  ('6', 'CERTIFICATE'),
  ('7', 'AMENDMENT'),
  ('8', 'NOTIFICATION'),
  ('9', 'EXTRACT'),
  ('10', 'PETITION'),
  ('11', 'NOTIFICATION'),
  ('12', 'MANIFESTATION'),
  ('13', 'OTHER'),
  ('14', 'REPRESENTATIONS');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select * from programming_language
where match(name)
against("java" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

| word_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | JAVA |
| 3 | java |

---

**Query #2**

```
select * from programming_language
where match(name)
against("java" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

| word_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | JAVA |
| 3 | java |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mV64UHTP3Cc63oQvfZTZ4A/1)

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE programming_language (
  `word_id` INTEGER,
  `name` VARCHAR(15)
);

ALTER TABLE `programming_language` 
ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `fi_name` (`name`) ;
-- This returns nothing


INSERT INTO programming_language
  (`word_id`, `name`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'SWIFT'),
  ('2', 'JAVA'),
  ('3', 'java'),
  ('4', 'javascript'),
  ('5', 'PETITION'),
  ('6', 'CERTIFICATE'),
  ('7', 'AMENDMENT'),
  ('8', 'NOTIFICATION'),
  ('9', 'EXTRACT'),
  ('10', 'PETITION'),
  ('11', 'NOTIFICATION'),
  ('12', 'MANIFESTATION'),
  ('13', 'OTHER'),
  ('14', 'REPRESENTATIONS');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select * from programming_language
where match(name)
against("java javascript" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

| word_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | javascript |
| 2 | JAVA |
| 3 | java |

---

**Query #2**

```
select * from programming_language
where match(name)
against("java*" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

| word_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | JAVA |
| 3 | java |
| 4 | javascript |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mV64UHTP3Cc63oQvfZTZ4A/2)

> An ngram is a contiguous sequence of n characters from a given sequence of text. The ngram parser tokenizes a sequence of text into a contiguous sequence of n characters. For example, you can tokenize “abcd” for different values of n using the ngram full-text parser.

So you need to configure ngram for 4 letter words https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search-ngram.html

Comment: If you add javascript, do you get both java and javascript returned when you look up “java”?

Comment: please use the fiddle to check, yes if i add javascript to the table and search for "java javascript" i get all rowsfull text swearch is a bit tricly and using a parser for japanese and chinese language even more.

Comment: Sorry, let me restate the question. Is it possible to find java and javascript by full text searching java? (Not javascript)

Comment: yes full text supports wildcards see changed answer

Answer (score 0):

When using ngram parser in MySQL, any ngram that contains stop words are ignored.

> the ngram parser excludes tokens that contain stopwords. For example, assuming ngram_token_size=2, a document that contains “a,b” is parsed to “a,” and “,b”. If a comma (“,”) is defined as a stopword, both “a,” and “,b” are excluded from the index because they contain a comma. [source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search-ngram.html#:%7E:text=ngram%20Parser%20Stopword%20Handling)

You can get the default stop word list by the following query: `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD;` ([doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html))

It should contain English words such as `a` or `i`. This means any ngram containing character `a` or `i` will be not indexed, and that's why you cannot search for the word `java`. Because when n=2 (default), any ngram will contain chracter `a` (ja, av, va).

To avoid this problem, you can disable the default stop word list by setting a server parameter [`innodb_ft_enable_stopword=OFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_enable_stopword), or create your own stop word list ([doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html)).